# iOS Application does not receive data message send by FCM payload

Tags: ios, swift, laravel, firebase-cloud-messaging, payload

I am trying to send data message from fcm payload by using Laravel framework as shown below.

```
$optionBuilder = new OptionsBuilder();
$optionBuilder->setTimeToLive(60*20)
              ->setContentAvailable(true)
              ->setCollapseKey('collapse_all');

$option = $optionBuilder->build();

$dataBuilder = new PayloadDataBuilder();
$dataBuilder->addData([
  'name'=> 'pushDataUpdate',
  'time'=> $message['time'],
  'location'=> $message['location'],
  'queue'=> $message['queue']
]);

$data = $dataBuilder->build();

$token = $fcm_token;
$downstreamResponse = FCM::sendTo($token, $option, null, $data);
                                
$dataSent = array(
  "title" => 'Update Data',
  "fcm_success" => $downstreamResponse->numberSuccess(),
  "fcm_failure" => $downstreamResponse->numberFailure(),
  "fcm_modification" => $downstreamResponse->numberModification(),
  "token_to_delete" => $downstreamResponse->tokensToDelete(),
  "token_to_modify" => $downstreamResponse->tokensToModify(),
  "token_to_retry" => $downstreamResponse->tokensToRetry(),
  "token_to_error" => $downstreamResponse->tokensWithError()
);
```

Payload Data Response pass back in Android.

```
Message data payload: {name=pushDataUpdate,  time=10/3/2022, location=End, queue=End}
Message data payload size more than 0
```

When I try to call this data message in iOS app it does not come back but it does come back in Android app. I saw that many online answer says that it will call didReceiveRemoteNotification func when coming back. However, my case is the data message did not pass back when I open the app, close the app or kill the app.

Below are my App Delegate code for the app

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
      do {
          sleep(1)
      }
    
      FirebaseApp.configure()

      if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
          options: authOptions,
          completionHandler: {_, _ in })
      } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
      }

      application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(removeBadgeNumber), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
      Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
      UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    
      return true
  }

  @objc func removeBadgeNumber() {
      UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
      print("badge: \(UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber)")
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions : Set<UISceneSession>) {
    
  }

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
      print("Notification click opened")
      let pushNotification = PushNotification()
      let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
      let title = userInfo["title"] as! String
      pushNotification.navigate(with: title)
      print(userInfo)
      completionHandler()
}

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
      print("Foreground notification")
      completionHandler([.alert,.badge,.sound])
}

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    var token = ""

    for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
      token = token + String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
    }

    print("Registration succeeded!")
    print("Token: ", token)
   }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult)
                   -> Void) {
    
      if let name = userInfo["name"]{
        
          if(name as? String == "pushDataUpdate"){
              var info = [String: Any]()
            
              info["location"] = userInfo["location"]
              info["time"] = userInfo["time"]
              info["queue"] = Int(userInfo["queue"] as! String)
            
              NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: DATA_NOTIFICATION), object: nil, userInfo: info)
          }
      }
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
  }
}



extension AppDelegate{
  func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
    
      print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
    
      let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
      NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
    
  }
}
```

May I know which steps that I code it wrong?

I can get the notification pass back from firebase but not the data message.

I am struggle at this part for days, hope anyone could help me with this.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Can you please attached the json format of your payload so get idea.

Comment: Hi Krunal, I have add the payload data pass back from Android.